# SecurityException open data intent from Gmail attachment

Tags: android, android-securityexception

I am getting this error:

**java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.google.android.gm.sapi.SapiUiProvider uri content://com.google.android.gm.sapi/_____________@gmail.com/message_attachment_external/#thread-f:1767858831150858747/#msg-f:1767858831150858747/0.1 from pid=14714, uid=10343 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()**

in this line:

`Cursor fileCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);`

manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\.gpx"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xml"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
            </intent-filter>
```